# Interop service error occured when using InternetExplorerClass

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, office-interop

i am trying to deploy an asp.net web service application to IIS 7.5. The application used .Net framework 3.5. dev machine is win 7 64bit. i have used following code snippet to create HTML and then convert it to pdf using Amyuni Document Converter 450.

```
private InternetExplorer internetExplorer = new InternetExplorerClass();
```

when i deploy the application in local development server it perfectly run but whn i deploy it using the local iis server it gives following error. any reasons for that.. i have used impersonate='true'

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change property in DComConfig for ie. 
Follow the next steps:

Start->Run->dcomcnfg->Component services>Computers>My Computer

Right click on My Computer and select Properties. On the Security COM tab set the Default Autethentication level and Default Impersonation level.